# ASP.NET Web Forms - Security of Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

simple but hard to solve question on Web Forms.

I enforced a role-based access on my web form application, but I would like to tailor the access based on WebForm or URL, something like

/Administration/* --> only admins
/Users/* --> admins and users
/* --> anonymous also

Any hint on how to do it on web.config?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<location path=”Admin”>
                <authorization>
                                <allow roles=”Admin” /> 
                                <deny users=”*” />
                <deny roles=”*” /> 
                </authorization>
</location>
```

or take a look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871 or http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx

Answer (score 1):

An easiest way would be to create local `web.config` files in each of your subfolders. Such local `web.config` would only contain the authorization information so that the built-in `UriAuthorizationModule` could do the rest for you.

For example, inside the /Admin folder create a `web.config` with

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
 <authorization>
   <allow roles="Admin" />
   <deny users="*" />
 </authorization>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

thus giving the access to only users who are administrators. Apply the same to other subfolders and you are done - under a condition that a role manager exists and provides the information about users' roles.

Creating local `web.config`s containing only the authorization data in each subfolder gives you fine-grained control over your authorization. The alternative would be to provide this information in the main `web.config` but it would soon become overloaded with many authorization nodes referring to different locations.